# Lenovo Q180 IdeaCentre - Linux / (U)EFI Boot

Tags: boot, uefi, lenovo-desktop-computer

Does anyone get the correct boot path to start Linux from hard disk in (U)EFI mode? After doing research, I know that is one of the "corrupted", not working as expected (U)EFI 2.0 firmware. After adding and succesfully persisting the boot path via "efibootmgr", the entry does not appear in BIOS menu or at U(EFI) bootloader (accessed by hitting F12 during boot).

I tries a lot of things, but I can only boot via (U)EFI by inserting a USB stick and select the Grub2 entry manually. Otherwise the BIOS tells me that there is "no valid boot media".

What I tried so far, without success:

- Reading efivars to get a working path
- Tried different Boot labels, e.g. "Red Hat Enterprise Linux", "Microsoft .."
- Using Windows default name / fallback: "bootmgr.efi"
- Different path efi/EFI, efi/EFI/grub, efi/EFI/Microsoft
- Diffetent bootloaders, e.g. "uboot", "syslinux", " "grub2"

Any Ideas?

P.S. Current HDD partition type is GPT, with the common structure using sda1 with vfat as EFI partition.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and spent over a week trying to solve it. The issue was that it was installing partially to the USB stick. I bought a cd burner/drive them used it instead of the USB stick. It worked perfectly after that simple change in procedure.